# should I go multiple switch or one big switch

Tags: switch, network, topology

So I have a 2.5Gbps NIC on my server PC, but my main questions are:
note: I'm using consumer grade switches

1. will a 2.5Gbps switch split the load with two 1 Gbps switch?
2. will the 1Gbps be better on internal switching than the multiple switches?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your workloads.

The left-hand topology has slightly higher latencies, in the range of microseconds - usually not noticeable. However, the server could serve multiple clients on different access switches with up to 2 Gbit/s in total.

The right-hand topology has slightly lower latency but the server can only deliver or receive 1 Gbit/s in total.

Comment: Thank you, my workload consist of spikes of 1Gbps per client connected. My target is 10 total clients, so worst case scenario is 10 Gbps of sudden bandwidth. By this, I should go for the left topology right?

Comment: That workload description is not sufficient. How do request systematically overlap? How frequent are requests/responses, so what chance is there for random overlap? *10 Gbps of sudden bandwidth* isn't possible in either scenario with the single server. If clients communication between themselves (again, workloads? pairings?), they're in a server role as well and the picture changes completely.